# Stop chrome back/forward two finger swipe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, swipe

I want to disable the two finger swipe that causes Chrome going back or forward.
I have a website where the user might lose progress on his work if he doesn't specifically saves.

I have tried using `window.onbeforeunload` but that doesn't seem to work if I have hashes in the url (back forward would change between www.example.com/work/#step1#unsaved www.example.com/work/#step0) and the event doesn't seem to trigger.

I was about to switch to another solution but today I noticed that in Google Docs it's completely disabled. How did they achieve that?

Comment: window.onbeforeunload require synchronous tasks. Maybe that was the problem with that approach.

Comment: Can you use the `onhashchange` event to detect when a swipe tries to change the hasn?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You're looking at the problem at the wrong level. OnBeforeUnload is simply not triggered because there is nothing being unloaded from the browsers perspective. Therefore you have, quite bluntly, implemented the wrong mechanism for versioning - fragments are for page states, not document states as you are using it now.

If you insist on maintaining state through hash fragments you need to use another mechanism to guard against page state changing. Since all current browsers support LocalStorage I'd use that. And well, while at it, put all the document state data there instead of in the URL, since that is how Google Docs does it and that is why they don't have this issue.

Comment: I already discovered that `onbeforeunload` doesn't work "I have tried using window.onbeforeunload but that doesn't seem to work "

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. If the user is horizontal scrolling in div, for example, sometimes they reach the end and then Chrome will trigger a page back or page forward action. This is orthogonal to the url hash. Google Docs somehow disables this.

Answer (score 109):

The top answer from: [Disable Chrome two fingers back/forward swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474930) worked for me. In your CSS file:

```css
html, body {
  overscroll-behavior-x: none;
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try specifying `overscroll-behavior-x` on the `html` element.

Comment: Thank you @Matt Sanders, this is great, that gesture is sometimes surprisingly easy to trigger with the horizontal scroll

Comment: Semi off topic, but it's worth noting that this also works on other elements. Which is especially useful if you want to keep the two finger swipe for the entire page, but want to disable it for specific sections that have horizontal scroll.

Comment: Save my day,!!! I was finding javascript solution, detecting Swipe left right and then preventDefault, but this is quite easy .... Thank

Comment: If you only want this in some elements, say `<canvas>`, you want to `addEventListener('mouseenter'/'mouseleave'` and attach/remove the class on `<html>`

Comment: does the trick on chrome

Answer (score 10):

Make the specific page open in a new tab/window by default (by putting target="_blank"> in hyperlink). That way there'll be no previous page to go back to.

Or prevent Horizontal Scrolling by default. To do that, you can use jquery.mousewheel to do:

```
$(document).on("mousewheel",function(event,delta){ 
  // prevent horizontal scrolling
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX !== 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } 
});
```

Comment: It's better to use "event.stopPropagation()"

Comment: @sheerun No it's not. stopPropagation kills the event which might lead to unexpected behavior and bugs in third party code that relies on these events to be fired. Always prefer preventDefault. 
Also, preventDefault doesn't seem to be working anymore for this case in  Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (and neither does stopPropagation). Does anyone have a solution to that?

Comment: Yep, just got bit by this on Chrome 60 D:

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have a horizontal-scrolling element, adding `overscroll-behavior-x: contain;` is the easiest way prevent the scroll action from spilling out into the page and causing the navigation.

https://dev.to/danburzo/css-micro-tip-prevent-history-navigation-on-horizontally-scrolling-elements-3iil

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-overscroll-behavior

Comment: This does not seem to prevent the back navigation from happening while horizontally scrolling on Chrome in Windows. Edit: Apparently is does work when the property is on the `html` tag and not the scrollable container.

Answer (score 8):

Disable or replace swipe gestures for Google Chrome 61

The question that leads me here was marked "duplicate" and closed to answers. I believe this answer is better suited for the "duplicated" question, however, I feel this answer could possibly save time for someone landing on either question.

Better question:
[Disable navigation swipe on Chrome browser in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415370/disable-navigation-swipe-on-chrome-browser-in-javascript)

This Google developers article helped me to allow the e.preventDefault() to work and prevent swipe gestures as of Chrome 61.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention

givanse's answer to the following was the code that I used to write my own swipe event handlers:

[Detect a finger swipe through JavaScript on the iPhone and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android#23230280)

In summary, the following two events are used to implement the swipe gestures:

```
handleTouchStart (e) {
  ...
},
handleTouchMove (e) {
  ...
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

As of Chrome 56, the default behavior is to make the event listeners passive and thus disable the ability to prevent Chrome's swipe gestures. To override this behavior, event listeners can be added as follows:

```
document.addEventListener(
  'touchstart',
  this.handleTouchStart,
  {passive: false}
)
document.addEventListener(
  'touchmove',
  this.handleTouchMove,
  {passive: false}
)
```

By passing the {passive: false} object as the third parameter to the addEventListener method, the listener is registered as active and can stop Chrome's default behavior with the e.preventDefault() event method.

Answer (score 2):

Building on both the previous answers given by @roy riojas and @redgetan - I combined their answers to allow for this to be dynamic and prevent both forward and backwards - again - per @roy's comments - you must know the class of your element, and for this implementation - the class of the nested element that is actually being scrolled

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).on('mousewheel', function(e) { 
    var $target = $(e.target).closest('.scrollable-h');
    var scroll = $target.scrollLeft();
    var maxScroll = $target.find('.scrollable-h-content').width() - $target.width();

    if(scroll <= 0) {
      if(scroll <= 0 && e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX >= 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
    if(scroll >= maxScroll) {
      if (scroll >1 && e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX <= 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
});}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on something similar where I want to override the forward/backward history swiping gesture. Depending on what your swipe area is you can tweak the selector as follows:

```
html { touch-action:none; }
```

This is the associated documentation that gives you all the properties to all touch actions like panning or zooming features built into the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Comment: Didn't help me in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable back/forward with this code:

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Note that adding { passive: false } is essential, at least in Chrome. If you only want to disable back/forward in certain areas you can use code like this (assuming you're using jquery and you add the class disable-back-forward to the sections where you want to disable back/forward):

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.disable-back-forward').length)
        event.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this worked for me on chrome but not for the entire page, but for places where I have scrollable content.

In Google Docs (Spreadsheets) it seems to be working because they don't have a back page to go. If you navigate to another URL (manually) it will not prevent you from navigating back.

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', function(e) { 
  var $target = $(e.target).closest('.scrollable-h');
  if ($target.scrollLeft () <= 4) {
    $target.scrollLeft(5);
    return false;
  }
});
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the code above is making two assumptions:

1. your element with horizontal scrollable content has a class *scrollable-h*
2. If checks if the scrollLeft if bigger less than 4px and then just make it scroll to 5px
   returning false effectively cancel the back gesture

Important:
- This only prevents the back swipe gesture, when is done fast, if you do it very slow it will still trigger sometimes.

- Also this does not prevent the forward swipe gesture, but it could also be done by checking if the element has reached the maximum scrollLeft. If that is the case then move it 20px back and return false to prevent the event from happening... It is up to you to add this use case if it happens to make sense to you.

You can take a look to a proof of concept here. http://jsfiddle.net/royriojas/JVA6m/#base

Comment: So how do you prevent the bounce? It seems the only way to detect whether we are at the edge is after the scroll occurse, and not before

Comment: @KevinNewman I want to thank you so much. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out why the `preventDefault` on the `wheel` event didn't work for me. But then I noticed the word "bounce" in your comment and suddenly realized. I used the `_.throttle` on my event handler which was breaking the `preventDefault`. This is not related to the original question, but anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable it by typing chrome://flags in the address bar and heading down to "Overscroll history navigation" and setting it to "Disabled" from the dropdown.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Windows 10 Chrome v91

Answer (score 0):

Posting a **non-CSS answer**, which sometimes you don't have access to.

Run `chromium` / `chrome` with the `disable-features=OverscrollHistoryNavigation` :

```bash
# Run Chromium or Chrome with following flag
chromium --disable-features=OverscrollHistoryNavigation
```

Other gesture-related flags are usually recommended (such as the one that **disables zooming via pinch**, `--disable-pinch`), can be found here: https://niek.github.io/chrome-features/, which is a blog post recommended on the official docs ([here, down bottom](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/main/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md))