# Disable 2 finger swipe back navigation in Chrome on OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, swipe-gesture

I am using Chrome in `--app` mode on my local server. This works fine and makes it look like a native app although it's all HTML. However, if the Mac user does a 2 finger swipe left, then Chrome navigates back and to the previous page which does not work well with the interaction model on that app. So:

Can I disable that somehow, maybe via parameter when starting Chrome?

I know this feature comes from OSX and can be disabled by changing the system wide settings of chrome by running this command:

`defaults write com.google.Chrome.plist AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE`

However, this would also affect the user's other Chrome instances which he/she might not like. So can I either disable that for my instance (via parameter) or is there a Javascript solution to REALLY prevent a back function (not just auto forward again)?

Comment: I've also encountered the same headaches and provided a solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17031086/803865