# Disable Chrome two fingers back/forward swipe

Tags: google-chrome

I have a page where the user can scroll horizontally the content, and in Chrome this scroll action sometimes triggers the two fingers back/forward swipe.

How can I deactivate this Chrome's function in a specific page, without disabling horizontal scroll?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's possible to change it as a developer; only as a user. See [How do I disable Chrome's two-finger back/forward navigation?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/21236) and http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/PaMriZC-Kuo

Comment: Check my answer/example here (it may help): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829172/stop-chrome-back-forward-two-finger-swipe/45037801#45037801

Comment: Check my answer/example here (it may help): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829172/stop-chrome-back-forward-two-finger-swipe/45037801#45037801

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop chrome back/forward two finger swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829172/stop-chrome-back-forward-two-finger-swipe)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After way too long, I discovered this:

```
html, body {
  overscroll-behavior-x: none;
}
```

Comment: @MattSanders you probably need to set it on another DOM element. For me it works using the same Chrome version.

Comment: @gerric - hmm, thanks. Is it working for you on `body` or a different element?

Comment: In case this helps someone else, `body` and the element with `overflow` on it didn't work, but putting `overscroll-behavior-x` on the `html` element itself did work for me.

Answer (score 5):

I have found that this chrome setting disabled the behavior:
chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation

Just disable overscroll, it will disable the page navigation using the scroll but normal horizontal scroll on the page will work.
Tested on my end.

Comment: It seems that this no longer exists?

Comment: This still exists in Edge (chrome-based)

Answer (score 3):

Go to *Chrome flags* by pasting
**Chrome://flags** 
in the address bar and search for **Overscroll history navigation** and change 
this from default to **Disabled**

It will prompt to restart the browser, restart it.

This should solve it.

Comment: Finally I got rid of that nasty feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible to disable this feature by disabling scrolling itself:

**With jQuery:**

```
('body').on('wheel', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

**Without jQuery:**

```
document.body.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

This code will work in Modern browsers but is not cross-browser tested. Also, MAJOR CAVEAT: if you still want the users to be able to scroll the page, you'll have to roll your own scrolling to make it all work.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a **non-CSS answer**, which sometimes you don't have access to.

Run `chromium` / `chrome` with the `disable-features=OverscrollHistoryNavigation` :

```bash
# Run Chromium or Chrome with following flag
chromium --disable-features=OverscrollHistoryNavigation
```

Other gesture-related flags are usually recommended (such as the one that **disables zooming via pinch**, `--disable-pinch`), can be found here: https://niek.github.io/chrome-features/, which is a blog post recommended on the official docs ([here, down bottom](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/main/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md))