# Chromium: disable left swipe back navigation on RPi running in kiosk mode with Chromium?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, kiosk

I have a RPi 4 running in kiosk mode with a 7inch display which opens up Chromium at boot with the following parameters (which disable pinch zooming and info-bar):

```
chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch http://localhost
```

I am attempting to remove the back swipe navigation although I haven't been successful, here's the parameters I have passed with their respective sources:

```
chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch --disable-features="TouchpadOverscrollHistoryNavigation"
```

(found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/840102/how-do-you-disable-swipe-history-navigation-in-chrome))

```
chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0
```

(also found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/840102/how-do-you-disable-swipe-history-navigation-in-chrome))

```
chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch --back-gesture-horizontal-threshold=10000
```

(found [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#back-gesture-horizontal-threshold))
This last one was more an attempt to set the horizontal swipe to a ridiculous amount of pixels to prevent triggering the back navigation, but obviously it did not work.

I have also tried navigating to chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation and disabling it from there although in a new instance of Chromium this doesn't have any effect.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Well, I started a bounty to maybe solve this problem. However, I just found the solution right after this.

I also can confirm all chromium flags and command line switch don't work.

But I just found this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50846937/1990745

Add the following CSS:

```
html, body {
  overscroll-behavior-x: none;
}
```