# How to disable swipe right gesture programatically on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am developing a web app, and the user can switch between elements in a carousel by swiping left or swiping right. It works well on mobile devices, however Chrome on touch-enabled Windows devices overrides the swipe right gesture with a "go back" command. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop chrome back/forward two finger swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829172/stop-chrome-back-forward-two-finger-swipe)

Answer (score 0):

I happend to come across your question with the same problem. The problem is that you need hook up the touch events so the browser knows not to use swipe-back functionallity.

```
$(document).on("pointerdown", function (event) {

});
$(document).on("pointermove", function (event) {

});
$(document).on("pointerup", function (event) {

});
```